# insert data in on table from another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables called teams and players and I want to copy the field points from the table teams to the table players using the foreign key team in the table players which is the primary key id_team in the table teams. I need to have each player with the points of your own team. I'm trying

INSERT INTO players (points_team) SELECT points FROM teams WHERE

and here I don't know how to write the correct where sentence

Answer (score 0):

```
where id_team = (whatever you the fk/pk is named of the other table);
```

this will essential connect the fk to the pk of both the tables.